# How does a UILabel's minimumScaleFactor work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have used `minimumFontSize` before but that function is now deprecated and i don't quite understand how `minimumScaleFactor` works.

I want the maximum font size to be 10 and the minimum to be 7.

How can I achieve the re-size down to font size 7 with the scale factor?

`UILabel` creation:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
label.text =  [labelName uppercaseString];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:HELVETICA_FONT_STYLE_BOLD size:9.5];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.minimumScaleFactor = .1f;

[label addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[label(WIDTH)]"
                                                              options:0
                                                              metrics:@{@"WIDTH" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:buttonSize.width]}
                                                                views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];

[contentView addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 231):

You need to set the `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;`

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was missing in my own code. Thanks :D

Comment: Note: "Apple's documentation says the minimumScaleFactor only works if numberOfLines is set to 1. Using 0 or anything greater than 1 will not work." . Thanks SeanK.

Comment: Awesome! Funny that if you set minumumScaleFactor in the XIB you don't need to set the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth, but you need when doing in the code.

Answer (score 111):

In addition to what the other answers say, if you put minSize/defaultSize (division) as the `minimumScaleFactor`, it will be the same as using the old `minimumFontSize`.

Ex, if you want the minimum font size to be 10 using default label size, you can do:

`[label setMinimumScaleFactor:10.0/[UIFont labelFontSize]];`

(Replace `[UIFont labelFontSize]` with your label's font size if it is not the default).

which would be the same as:
`[label setMinimumFontSize:10.0];`

Comment: the division should be casted as CGFloat, otherwise it wouldn't work

Comment: @dwery Doing 10/labelSize may end up with a truncated integer value of 0 but 10.0 or 10.f work fine, without explicitly casting.

Comment: you're right, it should work. I can't remember in which code it didn't work for me, probably it was missing the f or the dot.

Answer (score 21):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html):

> Use this property to specify the smallest multiplier for the current font size that yields an acceptable font size to use when displaying the label’s text. If you specify a value of 0 for this property, the current font size is used as the smallest font size.

So if default font size for your label is `10`, you put `0.7f` as a `minimumScaleFactor`and it should do the same thing as `minimumFontSize` did.

Comment: Thats what i thought also; but even when i put it as 0.1f, the text does not adjust size. i'll add the uilabel code.

Comment: What if you remove constraints and just shrink label's frame?

Comment: Log139: What is your numberOfLines set to?  Apple's documentation says the minimumScaleFactor only works if numberOfLines is set to 1.  Using 0 or anything greater than 1 will not work.

Comment: @SeanK It will work even if numberOfLines is set to more than 1 but NOT 0.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to other answers, I'm going to add a beginner-friendly explanation that helped myself:

How to calculate a `minimumScaleFactor`? Divide your label's minimum font size by your label's default font size. For example, your default font size is 25. Your minimum font size is 10.

10/25 = 0.4

0.4 is your `minimumScaleFactor` value. Also see @Jsdodgers's answer above.