# UILabel Multiple Line in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, uilabel

I have to show multiple line in UILabel (If text is large). Below is my code. I am using separate properties for different iOS versions. Please help me out..

```
    labelLocation.numberOfLines=2;
    labelLocation.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue]>=6) {
        labelLocation.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        labelLocation.minimumScaleFactor=10.0/[UIFont labelFontSize];
    }else{
        labelLocation.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
        labelLocation.minimumFontSize=10;
    }
    labelLocation.text=@"Can we make UILabeltext in 2 lines if name is large";
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit about the problem that you have? BTW, do two lines of code actually fit into the label's frame?

Comment: I have Label with size 230x40. I need to show the text in two lines when text is large.

Comment: check my edited code and try to increase the frame of a label.

Comment: you can try labelLocation.numberOfLines=0;

Comment: Are you able to solve the iOS 6 multilines not working issue?

Answer (score 3):

these two line together works

```
labelLocation.numberOfLines=0;
labelLocation.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Comment: I increased the height, now its working. But minimumScaleFactor is not working. Any comment!

Comment: minimumScaleFactor means your label will reduces size upto scaleFactor u have defined if not filling whole text in label.It will not reduce font size more than that.read it http://stackoverflow.com/a/15332231/1305001

Answer (score 0):

you can set

```
 yourlabelname.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
 yourlabelname.numberOfLines = give how many lines you want for your label(e.g.2,3,etc...)
```

and check if your outlet is set properly.

Comment: Thanks for support, But I am already using that property. Look at first line of code.

Comment: Max two line. And I have used NSLineBreakByWordWrapping property. Not working

Comment: According to your code if it is going into else condition then you need to change **UILineBreakModeTailTruncation**. UILineBreakModeTailTruncation works only with one line label.

Comment: Please check the height and width of your label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `labelLocation.numberOfLines=0;`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that your label has to small height. Two lines in systemFontOfSize 25 need height about 60.
If label is to small, system doesn't wrap line.

Comment: I am also using minimumScaleFactor property!

Comment: This is effective only when numberOfLines = 1;

Answer (score 0):

change ur code to this

```
labelLocation.numberOfLines=0;
labelLocation.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40];
labelLocation.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakModeWordWrap;
labelLocation.text=@"Can we make UILabeltext in 2 lines if name is large";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend you to calculate the height required to show the text and then show it onto the label...never hard code text display components such as UITextView and UILable.

```
 NSString *str = @"This is to test the lable for the auto increment of height. This is only a test. The real data is something different.";


`UIFont * myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];//specify your font details here
//then calculate the required height for the above text.

CGSize lableSiZE = [str sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

//initialize your label based on the height you got from the above..you can put whatever width you prefer...

```
 UILabel *myLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, lableSiZE.width, lableSiZE.height)];

myLable.text = str;
myLable.numberOfLines=0;
myLable.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
//myLable.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
myLable.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```