# Difference between minimumFontSize and minimumScaleFactor in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I opened a existing project in xcode 7.2, I got a warning saying "minimum font size" is deprecated in ios 6.0.

I have changed it to minimum scale factor.

```
 labelDescription.numberOfLines  = 2;
 //labelDescription.minimumFontSize=10;       
 labelDescription.minimumScaleFactor = 10;
```

Does changing the property to minimum scale factor produce the same effect as minimum font size?

Comment: Yes. It is produce the same effects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a UILabel's minimumScaleFactor work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650990/how-does-a-uilabels-minimumscalefactor-work)

Comment: @JAGAT can you explain how ?

Comment: @YogarajR it is the font size. It is the minimum size of font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are the same but the `minimumFontSize` property of the `UILabel` is deprecated from iOS 6.0 onwards.

An Alternative to the `minimumFontSize` is `minimumScaleFactor`. If you assign `minimumFontSize/defaultFontSize` to `minimumScaleFactor`, it works in the same way as `minimumFontSize`.

The Code is as follows - For Example the font size is 30.0 and if you want the minimum font size to be 12.0

```
YOURLABEL.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"FONT_NAME" size:30.0];
[YOURLABEL setMinimumScaleFactor:12.0/[UIFont labelFontSize]];
```

Answer (score 1):

It produces the same effect, but you need to provide appropriate value for the minimum scale factor.

You should use values between x > 0 && x <= 1. This means if your font is 20, and your scale factor is 0.5, the minimum font size used for scaling will be 10.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/minimumScaleFactor) :

**minimumScaleFactor**

Use this property to specify the smallest multiplier for the current font size that yields an acceptable font size to use when displaying the label’s text. If you specify a value of 0 for this property, the current font size is used as the smallest font size.
(Available in iOS 6.0 and later)

**minimumFontSize**

When drawing text that might not fit within the bounding rectangle of the label, you can use this property to prevent the receiver from reducing the font size to the point where it is no longer legible.The default value for this property is 0.0. If you enable font adjustment for the label, you should always increase this value. This property is effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0)